# Why is MariaDB innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT so much slower than fsync for SELECT count(*) as count?

Tags: mariadb, performance-tuning, mariadb-10.5

I have a MariaDB 10.5.18 server with 64 GB of RAM running on an enterprise grade SSD.

I'm using a fairly generic my.cnf to try to figure out why `innodb_flush_method` O_DIRECT is so much slower than fsync for SELECT count(*) as count?

Here is the contents of my.cnf:

```
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8

open_files_limit = 50000
max_connections = 5000
max_connect_errors= 100000

key_buffer_size= 4096M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
bulk_insert_buffer_size= 2G

table_open_cache = 5000
connect_timeout= 30

skip-name-resolve = 1

query_cache_type= 0
tmp_table_size= 2G
max_heap_table_size= 2G

back_log= 10240
thread_cache_size= 400
```

With a default `innodb_flush_method` (fsync) doing `SELECT count(*) as count FROM ...` on a table with 64 million rows in it takes 62 seconds, +/- 1 second. This is very consistent (I restart the server in between tests and do similar queries on about 10 other tables beforehand).

Then I set the `innodb_flush_method` to O_DIRECT and restart the server and use the same methodology to test the same query and it takes 228 seconds, +/- 3 seconds.

This is with a very small `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of 128 MB, but the results are essentially the same with an `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of 16 GB. We intend to set it to more like 40 GB but my understanding is we can't do that with fsync due to the double buffering in the OS (as the amount of RAM used will be doubled, so an `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of 20 GB would use a total of 40 GB of RAM).

Why is fsync almost 4x faster than O_DIRECT?

Are there other changes we need to make to the OS (CentOS 7.9.2009)?

Is my understanding correct that fsync will double buffer in the OS and use twice the RAM?

**Update 1 (2023-02-23)**

The file system is EXT4. It is just mounted with "defaults", so there may be some optimization possible there.

```
CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `field3` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `field1_field2` (`field1`,`field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63799520 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Show Table Status

```
            Name: big_table
          Engine: InnoDB
         Version: 10
      Row_format: Dynamic
            Rows: 54975738
  Avg_row_length: 2710
     Data_length: 149004746752
 Max_data_length: 0
    Index_length: 2314207232
       Data_free: 5242880
  Auto_increment: 63799520
     Create_time: 2023-02-18 20:12:07
     Update_time: NULL
      Check_time: NULL
       Collation: utf8_bin
        Checksum: NULL
  Create_options:
         Comment:
Max_index_length: 0
       Temporary: N
```

Comment: Does this help:  https://www.percona.com/blog/watch-out-for-disk-i-o-performance-issues-when-running-ext4/

Comment: You're double buffering is quite wrong, take what memory you need. The OS will only cache on non-O_DIRECT is memory is available in a general LRU way. With low buffer pool I'd believe the count of `innodb_flush_method=flush` is faster, after the first one which should have about the same speed as `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, we're on kernel 3.10 so don't think that XFS bug applies. Thanks Dan for the clarification on double buffering. I dug deeper and this cleared up for me how it works: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,690969,691366#msg-691366

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Answer, but too long for a Comment.)

What filesystem?  ZFS, EXT, etc?  Does it have "journalling"?

Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of RAM (say, 40G).  128M is ridiculously small (and an old default).

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`.  (Obfuscated column names is OK, but datatypes and indexes are important.)

`tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` should be under 1% of RAM.

Are the other queries doing some writes?  `SELECT COUNT(*)` should be doing only reads *unless* the cache (buffer_pool) is full and needs writes.  (I would expect the flush_method to be irrelevant.)

I doubt seriously that the OS is caching just as much stuff as the buffer_pool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rick. I updated the post to include the info you requested. I also expected the flush_method to be irrelevant (or if anything for O_DIRECT to help), which is why I'm so stumped. I have multiple production servers I'd like to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` for but am hesitant to do so using fsync because I don't know the ramifications of double buffering.